# 32 bits apps don't work with nvidia 440 drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, opengl

Since I updated to nvidia 440 drivers when I run 32 bits apps (including the Steam GUI) I get the following error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
```

I was told that the solution was to install the 440 32bit drivers:
`sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-440:i386`

But I get the following message:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-gl-418 libnvidia-gl-430 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-ifr1-418
  libnvidia-ifr1-430 libnvidia-ifr1-440 nvidia-driver-440
```

So it makes me uninstall the drivers and the 64bit OpenGL drivers, I can't run any app after that point.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by purging all nvidia libraries `sudo apt get purge nvidia* libnvidia*` and reinstalling the drivers. `sudo apt get install nvidia-drivers-440`